# How to iterate over the series: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8, 9 … without using recursion?

Tags: c, sequence, series

Is am trying to figure out how to generate this sequence of numbers in C.

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9 …
```

The sequence is generated by forming a triangle of numbers as shown below:

```
0
1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8 9 ...
```

Next two numbers in series are located as follows:

1. Next number is located directly below
2. Next to next is located one place to the right.

```
0
|\
1 2

Series -> 0, 1, 2

0
|\
1 2
|\|\
3 4 5

Series -> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, ........
```

How can I traverse this number triangle to get this sequence in C?

It means that 
0 is replaced with 1 and 2
1 is replaced with 3 and 4
2 is replaced with 4 and 5

```
0
|\
1 2
|\|\
3 4 5
|\|\|\
6 7 8 9

Series -> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8, 9 ........
```

It means that

**I. Solving 0**

```
0 leads to 1 and 2

0 -> 1 - 2
0 1 2
```

**II. Solving 1 and 2**

```
1 leads to 3 and 4

1 -> 3 - 4
0 1 2 3 4

2 leads to 4 and 5

2 -> 4 - 5
0 1 2 3 4 4 5
```

**III. Solving 3, 4, 4, 5**

```
3 leads to 6 and 7

3 -> 6 - 7
0 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7

4 leads to 7 and 8

4 -> 7 - 8
0 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 7 8

4 leads to 7 and 8

4 -> 7 - 8
0 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 7 8 7 8

5 leads to 8 and 9

5 -> 8 - 9
0 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 7 8 7 8 8 9
```

My apologies for not explaining properly. I hope I explain it this time.

Comment: With your explanation, doesn't the series in the title have on pair `7,8` too much?

Comment: why `6, 7, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8, 9` and not `6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9`?

Comment: What's the next line? 10,11,11,12,**11,12**,11,12,12,13,**12,13**,12,13,13,14, or 10,11,11,12,**12,13**,11,12,12,13,**11,12**,12,13,13,14, (difference in bold)? My answer will generate the first, but your description also fits the second.

Comment: Please look into question again I had edited it. Hope its understandable this time ...

Comment: What have your tried so far? Please post your code.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks before posting my code I tried again to implement and I was successful.

Comment: 10 11 11 12 11 12 12 13 11 12 12 13 12 13 13 14 @Sjoerd thats the next line

Comment: @LusionNectar Thanks. My solution was wrong in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume (based on the description) your sequence should be indeed

```
 0
 1  2
 3  4  4  5
 6  7  7  8  8  9
10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14
```

etc.

You can work with it with the code like that:

```
int nextRowStart = 0;
int nextRowSize = 1;

for (int curr = 0; /*put some ending condition here*/; curr++)
{
    yield(curr)
    if (curr != nextRowStart - 1 && curr != nextRowStart)
        yield(curr);
    if (curr == nextRowStart)
    {
        nextRowStart += nextRowSize;
        nextRowSize++;
    }
}

void yield(int x)
{
    printf("%d ", x);
}
```

---

With the changed question, the new one can be done recursively

This is the solution in C#:

```
IEnumerable<int> Generate(int level)
{
    if (level == 0)
    {
        yield return 0;
        yield break;
    }

    int diff = level;
    foreach (int n in Generate(level - 1))
    {
        yield return n + diff;
        yield return n + diff + 1;
    }
}

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, maxLevel).SelectMany(Generate);
```

It would take some time to translate it into C...

---

C solution:

```
void Generate(int level, int* resultsize, int** result)
{
    if (level == 0)
    {
        *result = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        (*result)[0] = 0;
        *resultsize = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int recResultSize;
        int* recResult;
        Generate(level - 1, &recResultSize, &recResult);
        *resultsize = recResultSize * 2;
        *result = (int*)malloc(*resultsize * sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < recResultSize; i++)
        {
            (*result)[2*i]     = recResult[i] + level;
            (*result)[2*i + 1] = recResult[i] + level + 1;
        }
        free(recResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look into question again I had edited it. Hope its understandable this time ...

Comment: @Lusion: just added C# solution for your case, I'll try to map it to C code.

Comment: I had evaluated it via recursion, it'd be very helpful if it could be done non recursively using loops. Thanks

Comment: @Lusion: well, non-recursive solution needs studying the properties of the sequence, while the recursive one corresponds directly to your description -- that's why it's simpler :)

Comment: Check out my non recursive solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code which gives the exact result and solves the problem. I came at this result just when @Lundin asked me to post my code , I tried again and I was successful. Thanks guys.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int in;

int main(){
 int  ik, it, icount = 0, ih, temp, ig = 1;
 int aisum[100];
     aisum[0] = 0;
     scanf("%d",&in);
     printf("0\n");
     it = 1;ih = 0;temp = 2;
     for(icount = 0,ig = 1; icount <= in; icount++){
                for(ik = 0; ik<2; ik++){
                        aisum[ig] = aisum[icount] + it + ik ;
                        printf("%d ",aisum[ig]);
                        ig++;
                }

                if(aisum[icount] == ih){
                    printf("\n");
                    it++;
                    ih += temp;
                    temp++;
                }
     }

 return 0;
}
     /*Input the number of elements to be processed*/
     /*icount will account for new elements to be formed like if we look
     at pascal triangle
     0 will form 1 and 2
     1 will form 3 and 4
     */
     /*ig will account for array indices*/
     /*it will account for the periodic addition */
     /*ih checks for the codnition for it to increement
     0
     1 2
     3 4 5
     it will be increemented at 0, 2, 5 ...
     */
```

Comment: This should be good, the only issue I see is the static allocation of `aisum` array. You can actually precompute its desired size (taking into consideration that each row size is double the previous size, it's `2^maxlevel`) and allocate with `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can give from below triangle to required order is...

> 0
>
> 1 2
>
> 3 4 5
>
> 6 7 8 9

printing **start** and **end** nodes of each line and printing center elements 2 times each...

for each line start will be equals to previous end+1...

end will be equal to end+1+count...

count will be incremented by 1 for each line...

### CPP Program:

```
#include<iostream>    
using namespace std;    
int main()    
{    
    int start=1,end=2,count=1;    
    cout<<0<<" ";    
    while(count<5)    
    {    
        cout<<start<<" ";    
        for(int i=start+1;i<end;i++)    
        {    
            cout<<i<<" "<<i<<" ";    
        }    
        cout<<end<<" ";    
        count++;    
        start=end+1;    
        end=start+count;    
    }    
    return 0;    
}
```